# Getting 403 Forbidden while doing a post call, for hana sap

Tags: c#, .net

The idea is, there are two URL's, one will generate a x-csrf-token after get, and other will use that token as post.
So, token is getting generated, but post method returns 403 forbidden - csrf token validation failed.
I am getting the data using PostMan tool, but fails in code, my guess is the token expires as soon as its generated, while in postman it doesn't.

```
string Token = "";
            string URL = "someurl";
            string URL1 = "someurl.method()";
// GET
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URL);
            request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Headers["X-CSRF-Token"] = "Fetch";
            HttpWebResponse responseH = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Token = responseH.Headers["x-csrf-token"];
// POST

            string result = "";
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                string json = "{\"HEAD_HEAD\":[{\"VTWEG\":\"10\",\"KUNAG\":\"1000002\",\"KUNRG\":\"1000002\",\"KUNWE\":\"1000002\",\"KONDM\":\"1A\",\"DATAB\":\"04/18/2017\",\"VSBED\":\"71\",\"HEAD_ITEM\":[{\"Price\":\" \"},{\"Price\":\" \"}]},{\"VTWEG\":\"10\",\"KUNAG\":\"1000000\",\"KUNRG\":\" \",\"KUNWE\":\"1000000\",\"KONDM\":\"B9\",\"DATAB\":\"04/18/2017\",\"VSBED\":\"11\",\"HEAD_ITEM\":[{\"Price\":\" \"},{\"Price\":\" \"}]},{\"VTWEG\":\"10\",\"KUNAG\":\"1000000\",\"KUNRG\":\" \",\"KUNWE\":\"6000004\",\"KONDM\":\"2G\",\"DATAB\":\"04/18/2017\",\"VSBED\":\" \",\"HEAD_ITEM\":[{\"Price\":\" \"},{\"Price\":\" \"}]}]}";
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                client.Headers["X-CSRF-Token"] = Token;
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/json";
                string userName = "username";
                string passWord = "password";
                string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName + ":" + passWord));
                client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + credentials;
                result = client.UploadString(URL1, "POST", json);
            }
```